# Church hope them issue

Tags: themes, theme-options

I'm using the church home theme and can't figure out how to modify the three images under the download button page.

http://themeforest.net/item/churchope-responsive-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/2708562

they say         life groups , New here, Every Penny helps

The appear on my home page and its the default content.

Comment: You paid to get support and documentation. Have you tried both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme calls these "Teasers," and they are set by using shortcodes on your home page.  More info can be found on your theme's [online documentation](http://churchope.themoholics.com/online-documentation/teasers-shortcode/).

Comment: ahh ok thanks :), what about the latest sermons bit? http://themeforest.net/item/churchope-responsive-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/2708562

Comment: From [your theme's FAQ](http://churchope.themoholics.com/faq/), read this: [How to add latest sermon...](http://churchope.themoholics.com/faq/#3-1).  Please try reading the FAQ before you ask another question.  :)